# How to use the Ansible uri module to POST a file as form-data?

Tags: post, sonarqube, ansible, multipartform-data

SonarQube allows the upload of a `profile.xml` file via form-data `POST` request as follows:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST http://sonar:9000/qualityprofiles/restore -F backup=@profile.xml
```

I'm trying to translate this `curl` command into Ansible, using the `uri` module. Unfortunately, I don't see any chance to map the `-F` form-data option and the parameter `backup` to Ansible. Here's my attempt:

```
- name: create quality profile
  uri:
    url: "{{ sonar_api_url }}/qualityprofiles/restore"
    method: POST
    body: "{{ lookup('file', 'profile.xml') }}"
    user: "{{ sonar_admin_user }}"
    password: "{{ sonar_admin_pass }}"
    force_basic_auth: "yes"
    status_code: 200
```

I've also tried something like this:

```
    body: "backup={{ lookup('file', 'profile.xml') }}"
```

Or just like this:

```
    body: "backup=profile.xml"
```

But all without success. I keep getting the error "A backup file must be provided". Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: AFAIK, `uri` module doesn't support file uploading

Comment: not a direct solution to the file posting, but it seems that you like to script the setup of your quality profile. I ran into the same issue and solved it by using the Sonarqube api: `http://localhost:9000/api/qualityprofiles/activate_rule`

Comment: but you have to convert your profile.xml to a yaml file e.g: `sonarqube_update_rules_checkstyle:
  - key: checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.coding.RequireThisCheck
    severity: MAJOR
    params: checkFields=true;checkMethods=true`

Answer (score 8):

I also tried many options with the Ansible `uri` command with no luck despite being able to use the API via `uri` for things like setting Authentication etc.

I did succeed however using a parameterised `shell: curl` command:

**Set Vars:**

```
vars:
  sonar_api_url: "https://yoursonarqubeserver.com/api"
  sonar_token: "YourSonarQubeApiTokenThatRequiresAdminRights"
  sonar_profile: "YourSonarQubeProfileToLoad.xml"
```

**Task:**

```
- name: POST a SonarQube Profile xml via curl
  shell: 'curl  -X "POST" "{{ sonar_api_url }}/qualityprofiles/restore" \
                -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=__X_PAW_BOUNDARY__" \
                -u {{ sonar_token }}: \
                -k \
                --form backup=@{{ sonar_profile }}'
```

Note the API token is passed in as the username with a plank password via the curl -u.

I also have a [sample GitHub repo](https://github.com/JeremyNevill/ansible-sonarqube-config) with a working example you can refer to.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: The [uri module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/uri_module.html) does support the file upload now. Depending on if the file is located on the controller or on master or remote machine you will need to set `remote_src` flag. The remote feature [has been added in the 2.7 release.](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/33689#issuecomment-380639841)

Comment: Please show an example of one that works.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate a bit more on @Ninroot answer. You can now with the [uri module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/uri_module.html) make a post as if you would be doing a form post, example in the documentation. Be sure you have ansible version >=2.9. Another example could be as follow:

```
- name: Call upload endpoints
  uri:
    url: "url to use"
    method: "POST"
    body_format: "form-multipart"
    body:
      backup:
        filename: "{{ playbook_dir + '/files/file.pdf' }}"
        mime_type: application/octet-stream
      anotherFormParam: "api_key"
    user: "user"
    password: "pass"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    return_content: yes
    headers:
      Content-Type: multipart/form-data
    validate_certs: false
  register: upload_result
```

Answer (score 0):

Lookups occur on the local computer, not on the remote computer ([link](http://ansible-docs.readthedocs.io/zh/stable-2.0/rst/playbooks_lookups.html#intro-to-lookups-getting-file-contents)), So maybe when you run your playbook on a remote machine it cant find the file... (template won't help for it puts the file in the target machine)

You can read the file contents into a variable as a pre-action (using cat..) and than use that var in the body property of the URI module.